# Calling a Serenity service endpoint and react to success or failure on client-side

Tags: web-services, serenity-platform

Until recently (one of the last full .net SF versions), I could call a Serenity service endpoint like below and react on success or failure. With current .net core (3.14.3) SF, somehow this seems not anymore to work.

I just get a dialog with the message content. I neither get "success" nor "error" alert box.

[image]

**Question:** How to do this with current SF 3.14.3.

Here my code from a project on full .net where this still works:

```
let bla1 = CountriesService.ImportCountriesFromRESTCountries(
{

},
response => {
    
    alert('success');

    let message = JSON.parse(bla1.responseText);

    Q.notifySuccess(message, Q.text("Dialogs.Button.UpdateCountries.Import.Toast.Title"), options);
    this.refresh();

},
{
    blockUI: true,
    onError: response => {


        alert('error');
        
        let errorcontent = JSON.parse(bla1.responseText);
        let message = errorcontent["Error"]["Message"]
        Q.alert(message);

        this.refresh();

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

face same issue , i resolved this by

```
 Q.serviceCall<Serenity.RetrieveResponse<any>>({
                    service: this.serviceUrl + '/Retrieve',
                    request: {
                        EntityId: this.value                       
                    } as Serenity.RetrieveRequest,
                    async: false,
                    onSuccess: (response) => {
                        this._selectedItem = response.Entity;
                    },
                    onError: (error) => {
                       console.log( error.Error);
                    }
                });
```